# Identify Encoding and Decode Byte Array to String

Tags: c#, character-encoding

I have a function that returns a byte array that represents a JSON string I need to parse. Generally, I would use `Encoding.Default.GetString(myByteArray)` to convert it to a string, but the resulting string has some unrecognized characters in it: `?{"rects":[],"text":""}` instead of `{"rects":[],"text":""}`.

I have tried using every other encoding scheme the `Encoding` class has (that I know of anyway): `UTF8`, `UTF7`, `UTF32`, `Unicode`, `BigEndianUnicode`, `Latin1`, and `ASCII`, but every single one resulted in a string with `?`, `??`, or `ÿ_` at the beginning (or in the case of UTF32, the whole string was `?`'s).

Strangely, using `new StreamReader(new MemoryStream(myByteArray)).ReadToEnd()` decoded the string perfectly, and is what I'm currently using in my code. I used `StreamReader.CurrentEncoding` to figure out what encoding it was using and printed it to the console (`System.Text.UnicodeEncoding`), then tried using `new UnicodeEncoding().GetString(myByteArray)`, but still no luck.

How do I identify what encoding the byte arrays are using so I can decode it directly instead of wrapping it in streams?

```cs
// data is the example JSON string: {"rects":[],"text":""}
// In practice, the JSON strings are much longer.
var data = new byte[] { 255, 254, 123, 0, 34, 0, 114, 0, 101, 0, 99, 0, 116, 0, 115, 0, 34, 0, 58, 0, 91, 0, 93, 0, 44, 0, 34, 0, 116, 0, 101, 0, 120, 0, 116, 0, 34, 0, 58, 0, 34, 0, 34, 0, 125, 0 };

var ms = new MemoryStream(data);
var sr = new StreamReader(ms);

var text = sr.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(sr.CurrentEncoding);
Console.WriteLine(text);

var text2 = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);

Console.WriteLine(text2);

dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(text);

Console.WriteLine(json.text);
Console.WriteLine(json.rects);
```

Thanks!

Comment: new UnicodeEncoding() works for me (does not produce ? at the beginning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have UTF-16 with **B**yte **O**rder **M**ark ([BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) which defines the encoding. In your case BOM is `FE` which is `UTF-16 (LE)`:

```
var data = new byte[] { 
  255, 254, // <- BOM (UTF-16 (LE))
  123, 0, 34, 0, 114, 0, /* Payload */ };
```

So you can just get rid of **BOM** and decode the rest:

```
string result = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data.AsSpan(2));
```

Note, that file readers (like `StreamReader`) can [detect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-io-streamreader-ctor(system-io-stream-system-boolean)) **BOM**, get the correct decoder and use it when reading the file.

Comment: That was it, thanks! I had tried to use `Substring(2)` to skip the first 2 ?'s after decoding the array and ran into other issues with deserializing later in the string, but removing the the first two bytes in the array *before* decoding worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

What are the first two bytes for? Look what characters 255 and 254 are
https://ascii-tables.com/
just remove them and it should work fine